# How to filter arrya with keys in object and create new object

Tags: javascript, react-native, filter

How can I filter the rooms array with elements in the object and if it matches to object id in the array of objects with item type "Room"  add count key with count to the main array?

The First Array that I get from API

```
[ 
  {
    rooms: [ 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '8c6a6070-80c0-11eb-9753-bb149505e85f',
    itemName: 'Item 1’,
  },
  {
    rooms: [ 'eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3aede320-870f-11eb-9e58-9d6fb0d8b5a8',
    itemName: 'Item 2'
  },
  {
    rooms: [ 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3ad52b00-870f-11eb-8f84-0782ebd81006',
    itemName: ‘Item3’ 
  },
  { 
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom’
  },
  { 
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom 2' 
  },
 ]
```

I want to filter the rooms array with elements in the object and if it matches to object id in the array of objects with itemtType "Room"  add count key with count to main array as below.

```
[ 
{
    rooms: [ 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '8c6a6070-80c0-11eb-9753-bb149505e85f',
    itemName: 'Item 1’,
},
  {
    rooms: [ 'eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3aede320-870f-11eb-9e58-9d6fb0d8b5a8',
    itemName: 'Item 2'
 },
  {
    rooms: [ 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5' ],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3ad52b00-870f-11eb-8f84-0782ebd81006',
    itemName: ‘Item3’ 
},
  { 
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom’,
    count: 2
 },
  { 
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom 2',
    count: 1
},
 ]
```

Comment: Where did the `categories` key in the expected output come from?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan i have edited the question category is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the input array and add the `count` property to the elements with an `itemType` of `'Room'`. You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to count the number of rooms.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    rooms: ['f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5'],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '8c6a6070-80c0-11eb-9753-bb149505e85f',
    itemName: 'Item 1',
  },
  {
    rooms: ['eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5'],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3aede320-870f-11eb-9e58-9d6fb0d8b5a8',
    itemName: 'Item 2',
  },
  {
    rooms: ['f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5'],
    itemType: 'Item',
    id: '3ad52b00-870f-11eb-8f84-0782ebd81006',
    itemName: 'Item3',
  },
  {
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'f03e6e40-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom',
  },
  {
    itemType: 'Room',
    id: 'eef60fc0-870d-11eb-88a2-0149a30c02c5',
    itemName: 'Bedroom 2',
  },
]

const result = arr.map((element) => {
  if (element.itemType !== 'Room') {
    return element
  }
  return {
    ...element,
    count: arr.filter(
      (i) => i.itemType === 'Item' && i.rooms.includes(element.id)
    ).length,
  }
})

console.log(result)
```